# Styling Echo Errors

Tags: php, css, forms, authentication

I've created a register page which will echo out the errors if validation doesn't pass. The errors will always appear on the top of the form. I want them to appear beneath the form, so I added a div. But this doesn't work as it makes each error have an individual div, instead of having all of the errors in one div. How do I make all of the errors in one div which is underneath the form?

```
if (Input::exists()) {
    if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        //validation

        if ($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();
            //pass information to database

                Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered and can now log in!');
                Redirect::to('index.php');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo '<div id="r-error"><p id="error">', $error, '</p></div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Besides putting a div out of the loop, remove id attribute from the p tag. ID must be unique for each element. Either use class or don't use anything at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the `<div>` out of the loop. Echo the opening before the loop and then echo the closing after the loop.

```
if (Input::exists()) {
    if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        //validation

        if ($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();
            //pass information to database

                Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered and can now log in!');
                Redirect::to('index.php');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            echo '<div id="r-error">';
            foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo '<p class="error">', $error, '</p>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Also id shouldn't be used for p tag, as it won't be unique in case there are several errors.

Comment: Hah, I was just editing that as your comment came in. I didn't realize it was an id initially, changed it to a class.